# Score text based on found value's

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to know how I can score my dataframe based on  values found with `grep()`.
Say I got a DF Containing this:

```
age=c("France","Mars","Jupitor","Moon","Sun","Afrika","Texas","Michigan","Washington","Kiev","Amsterdam","Norway")
height=c("Paris","Planet","Planet","COLD","HOT!","LIONS","Austin","Lansing","WashingtonDC","Ukrain","Holland","Oslo")
village=data.frame(age=age,height=height)
```

and I use `grep('Moon',village$age, ignore.case=TRUE)` to search which row it is on.
How can you add a column in front of age, to score it with in example, the number 1,
if I use `grep('FRANCE',village$age, ignore.case=TRUE)`  to score it with the number 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what the non-found "scores" should be, so the following just uses `NA`'s:

```
age <- c("France","Mars","Jupitor","Moon","Sun","Afrika",
         "Texas","Michigan","Washington","Kiev","Amsterdam","Norway")

height <- c("Paris","Planet","Planet","COLD","HOT!","LIONS",
            "Austin","Lansing","WashingtonDC","Ukrain","Holland","Oslo")

village <- data.frame(score=NA, age=age, height=height)

print(village)

##    score        age       height
## 1     NA     France        Paris
## 2     NA       Mars       Planet
## 3     NA    Jupitor       Planet
## 4     NA       Moon         COLD
## 5     NA        Sun         HOT!
## 6     NA     Afrika        LIONS
## 7     NA      Texas       Austin
## 8     NA   Michigan      Lansing
## 9     NA Washington WashingtonDC
## 10    NA       Kiev       Ukrain
## 11    NA  Amsterdam      Holland
## 12    NA     Norway         Oslo

village[grep('moon', village$age, ignore.case=TRUE),]$score <- 1
village[grep('france', village$age, ignore.case=TRUE),]$score <- 2

print(village)

##    score        age       height
## 1      2     France        Paris
## 2     NA       Mars       Planet
## 3     NA    Jupitor       Planet
## 4      1       Moon         COLD
## 5     NA        Sun         HOT!
## 6     NA     Afrika        LIONS
## 7     NA      Texas       Austin
## 8     NA   Michigan      Lansing
## 9     NA Washington WashingtonDC
## 10    NA       Kiev       Ukrain
## 11    NA  Amsterdam      Holland
## 12    NA     Norway         Oslo
```

Comment: Thank you loads! also a very fast response, very helpful!